# How to find the difference between today and another date in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a function that tells me the difference between today and another date. If that date is less then a month from now, it displays TEXT1, if it is more than a month from now, it displays TEXT2. Also, if it displays TEXT1, it should also make the cell a certain color.

Comment: For difference you may just subtract the dates. For iteration you may just use the if clause.

Comment: =IF(TODAY()<"DATEVALUE(D2)-31";"ALL GOOD";"RECERTIFICATION")
This is what I've tried

Comment: try this one: `=IF(TODAY()-D2>30;"ALL GOOD";"RECERTIFICATION")`. For `if it displays TEXT1, it should also make the cell a certain color.` look into [Conditiona; formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx)

Comment: This one worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own UDF (user defined function) that achieves the first part of the above. Unfortunately UDF's cannot alter the cell other than to return a value. Place the following code into a module in your workbook for it to work.

```
          Public Function DateCompare(EvalDate As Date) As String
            Dim cval As Integer

            cval = EvalDate - Date

            Select Case cval
                Case Is <= 30
                    DateCompare = "TEXT 1"
                Case Is > 30
                    DateCompare = "TEXT 2"
            End Select

         End Function
```

Comment: To use the function, enter it as a standard Excel function. The example here assumes you're evaluating a date in cell A2 `=DateCompare(A2)`